# Mesh is colored, enough though I don't give it any color

Tags: c++, graphics, directx-11

I am not giving the vertex shader any color, but it renders the mesh with different colors. You can see it here

[image]

I have no idea why it gets colored like that, any ideas?

Here are my shaders

```
cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 gWorldViewProj; 
};

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 Pos  : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH  : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;

    // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
    vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.Pos, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);

    // Just pass vertex color into the pixel shader.
    vout.Color = vin.Color;

        return vout;
}

float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target
{
    return pin.Color;
}

technique11 ColorTech
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_5_0, PS() ) );
    }
}
```

And here is the part where I initializing the pipelines:

```
    HRESULT result;

    GeometryGenerator::MeshData grid;
    GeometryGenerator geoGen;
    geoGen.CreateGrid(160.0f, 160.0f, 50, 50, grid);
    m_gridIndexCount = grid.indices.size();

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices(grid.vertices.size(),Vertex(XMFLOAT3(0,0,0),XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,0)));
    for (UINT i = 0; i < grid.vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        XMFLOAT3 p = grid.vertices[i].Position;
        p.y = GetHeight(p.x, p.z);

        vertices[i].pos = p;
        /*
        if (p.y < -10.0f)
        {
            //sandy beach color
            vertices[i].color = XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.96f, 0.62f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (p.y < 5.0f)
        {
            //light yellow-green color
            vertices[i].color = XMFLOAT4(0.48f, 0.77f, 0.46f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (p.y < 12.0f)
        {
            //dark yellow-green color
            vertices[i].color = XMFLOAT4(0.1f, 0.48f, 0.19f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (p.y < 20.f)
        {
            //dark brown color
            vertices[i].color = XMFLOAT4(0.45f, 0.39f, 0.34f, 1.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            //white snow color
            vertices[i].color = XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }*/
    }

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexDesc, sizeof(vertexDesc));
    vertexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vertexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex)* grid.vertices.size();
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA resourceData;
    ZeroMemory(&resourceData, sizeof(resourceData));
    resourceData.pSysMem = &vertices[0];
    result = m_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexDesc, &resourceData, &m_pVertexBuffer);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&indexDesc, sizeof(indexDesc));
    indexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    indexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    indexDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* m_gridIndexCount;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA indexData;
    ZeroMemory(&indexData, sizeof(indexData));
    indexData.pSysMem = &grid.indices[0];
    result = m_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&indexDesc, &indexData, &m_pIndexBuffer);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#if defined _DEBUG || defined DEBUG
    shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    ID3D10Blob *compiledShader = 0;
    ID3D10Blob *compilationMsgs = 0;
    result = D3DX11CompileFromFile("SolidColor.fx", 0, 0, 0, "fx_5_0", shaderFlags,
        0, 0, &compiledShader, &compilationMsgs, 0);

    if (compilationMsgs != 0)
    {
        MessageBox(0, (char*)compilationMsgs->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
        compilationMsgs->Release();
        compilationMsgs = 0;
    }
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "error", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    result = D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(),
        0, m_pd3dDevice, &m_pFx);
    compiledShader->Release();

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "error", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    m_pTechnique = m_pFx->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");
    m_pFxWorldViewProj = m_pFx->GetVariableByName("gWorldViewProj")->AsMatrix();


    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC solidColorLayout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    UINT numLayoutElements = ARRAYSIZE(solidColorLayout);
    D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc;
    m_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);

    result = m_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(solidColorLayout, numLayoutElements, passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &m_pInputLayout);

    return true;
```

Comment: I see you are using the Effects 11 system and the deprecated D3DX11 library from the legacy DirectX SDK. You should take a look at the latest version of FX11 which is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki). For one thing, it provides a ``D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile`` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because a vertex shader and a pixel shader must match on the output/input. Here, the SV_POSITION semantic is unused in the pixel shader and strip away. Because of that, the pixel shader read in the "register 0" the color, while the vertex shader write the color in "register 1" and the position in "register 0".

To fix it change your structure like that :

```
struct VertexOut
{
    float4 Color : COLOR;
    float4 PosH  : SV_POSITION;
};
```

Comment: I change the VertexOut struct ,but no changes have occurred in the results.

Comment: @zhangbaochong it is because you have an other bug, in solidColorLayout, the color stream should have an offset of 12. Right now, it read the vertex position as th color too

Comment: it's right! I change the solidColorLayout as follow  D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC solidColorLayout[] =
 {
  { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
  { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
 };

Comment: the sequence of Color and PosH may not influence the result，they are all right.